# How to obtain label pageref from AUX file?

Tags: cross-referencing, auxiliary-files

I would like to read the pageref info for labels directly from the Aux file. 
It seems that for every label `<label>` there is a macro `\r@<label>` that contains all the information and is accessible, for instance, to be used in `\typeout`. However, I'm interested only in the page number, so I would use `\pageref{<label>}`. But this doesn't work in `\typeout`. This is an MWE of my scenario where labels are generated using the value of a counter (updated):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol,hyperref}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{%
    \stepcounter{mycounter}
    \label{myitems@\themycounter}
    \typeout{Processing Item No \themycounter}
    \typeout{Label Info From Aux File Is 
        \csname r@myitems@\themycounter\endcsname}
    \typeout{Pageref From Aux File Is 
        \pageref{myitems@\themycounter}}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Section}]
    \mycommand
    \lipsum[1-10]
    \mycommand
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \mycommand
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

This produces the output

```
ProcessingItemNo1
LabelInfoFromAuxFileIs{1}{1}{Section}{section.1}{}
PagerefFromAuxFileIs\pageref {myitems@1}
[1]
ProcessingItemNo2
LabelInfoFromAuxFileIs{1}{3}{Section}{section.1}{}
PagerefFromAuxFileIs\pageref {myitems@2}
[2]
ProcessingItemNo3
LabelInfoFromAuxFileIs{1}{4}{Section}{section.1}{}
PagerefFromAuxFileIs\pageref {myitems@3}
[3] [4]
```

So it seems that the page information is already there at this point in the code (second token in `\r@<labelname>`) but `\pageref` cannot produce it.

My question is: How can I produce the page number at this point in the code (for use in `\typeout` or in other macro stuff)? Basically, I need a variable `\tmpa` that is fully expanded and just stores the page number for that label as restored from the AUX file. Is that possible?

**Edit:** 
After solving the problem I found that my MWE was not "minimal" enough to isolate the actual problem. So here is a simpler MWE showing what I was actually wondering about.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,multicol,hyperref}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
% this shows that all the info on mylabel (including page number) is available:  
\typeout{Label Info From Aux File Is \r@mylabel}
% but this shows that nevertheless, \pageref does not work:  
\typeout{Last time, mylabel was on page \pageref{mylabel}}
% this is, then, the solution to my problem, see my answer below: 
\typeout{Last time, mylabel was on page \getpagerefnumber{mylabel}}
\makeatother

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Section}]
    \lipsum[1-10]
    \label{mylabel}
    \lipsum[1-5]
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

So, I was just wondering why `\pageref` doesn't work in a situation where `\r@mylabel` is available and stores all relevant information from the AUX file.

Comment: `\refstepcounter` is the macro that you need for `\label`, not just `\stepcounter`

Comment: I don't think so as the counter is only used internally to generate the name of a new label. I don't want any `\ref{label}` to refer to this counter's value.

Comment: Oh no, your answer was helpful! And why does my labeling only work by chance??

Comment: Because the page number is always stored expanded to the `.aux` file, regardless whether you need the real cross-reference made by `\refstepcounter` or just using an ordinary incrementation. Since you rely on the page number it is just by chance that this is done anyway. (One could say: it works by a lucky 'design' decision' of the LaTeX developers)

Comment: Hm I think we might misunderstand each other. I updated my question to give an even simpler MWE. Sorry for the mess, but I think this is a relevant question and still didn't quite understand why `\pageref` doesn't work, although my problem is now solved.

Comment: `\pageref` isn't expandable, that's the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, I see that there is a simple solution by using `\getpagerefnumber{myitems@\themycounter}}` instead of `\pageref{myitems@\themycounter}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The page label reference value can be extracted with `\crtrefpage` from the `crossreftoolspackage` as well, which is an expandable command. There's no need to use `expl3` here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{crossreftools}

\makeatletter

\newcounter{mycounter}

\newcommand{\mycommand}{%
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  \label{myitems@\themycounter}
  \typeout{Processing Item No \themycounter}
  \typeout{Label Info From Aux File Is 
    \csname r@myitems@\themycounter\endcsname}
  \typeout{Pageref From Aux File Is \crtrefpage{myitems@\themycounter}}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}[\section{Section}]
  \mycommand
  \lipsum[1-10]
  \mycommand
  \lipsum[1-5]
  \mycommand
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I removed the latex3 commands from my MEW (it was a relict from a more complicated source). However, I found that just using `\getpagerefnumber` instead of `\pageref` solves my problem (see my own answer). Is there any reason to prefer your solution (which involves an extra package after all)?

Comment: @LaTechneuse: No, there's no advantage, it's just another solution